# How to Solve Heroku Deployment Error using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment, command-line-interface, heroku-cli

When I try to deploy my website onto heroku using [this tutorial](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/deploy-static-site-heroku) it is not working. It returns the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:670
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '"/Applications/Visual'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:668:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:591:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:19)
    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:945:12)
    at loadPreloadModules (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:363:5)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:61:3)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:11:1
```

Comment: how are you requiring this in your node server ? can you past that

Comment: @Sven.hig What do you mean by that?

Comment: /Applications/Visual in your node server, the code you wrote to require it can you coy and  paste it here

Comment: @Sven.hig Here are my imports:

const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const browsersync = require("browser-sync").create();
const cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");
const del = require("del");
const gulp = require("gulp");
const header = require("gulp-header");
const merge = require("merge-stream");
const plumber = require("gulp-plumber");
const rename = require("gulp-rename");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");

// Load package.json for banner
const pkg = require('./package.json');